# How to clear Google Proxy or googleusercontent.com cache?

Tags: java, php, html, email, caching

A wrong image file has been cached by Gmail's [Google Proxy](https://filippo.io/how-the-new-gmail-image-proxy-works-and-what-does-this-mean-for-you/) that runs under googleusercontent.com and we are looking into deleting the cache. The original file is linked from Amazon S3. We want to force a cache invalidate, so emails sent yesterday (5M) display the correct image.

Facebook has the Linter page but how do we do on Google Proxy?

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it is not about programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doubt you can clear the cache from Google's servers. The reason why they started this is to address is to prevent spam. However by doing so, it caused some problems to surface like broken links.

Somebody asked the question of when do they clear the cache and nobody replied. Not even Google's staff. [Gmail forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/w_1FzYUa00k/sXvNFbVmBGcJ;context-place=msg/gmail/W3P-npbkfAE/MIRLzupaqQMJ)
It looks like they do not intend to allow users to overwrite/delete/update the cached images. Perhaps in the future, as a free-mium feature?

However you can prevent it from happen by applying the no-cache header next time. This allows the images in your email to not be cached.

```
HTTP 200 OK
Content-Type: image/png
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0
```

http://blog.movableink.com/real-time-content-and-re-open-tracking-return-to-gmail/

A detailed explanation of how the caching works can be found here. 
http://www.redant.com.au/how-we-do/cache-busting-gmail-new-image-caching/

Comment: even Facebook has the Linter page, so it might be useful one from Google - they should build one too.

Comment: yup, but the issues comes to who claims which content etc etc and will it come under abuse.